# Use attributes in layout

Tags: android, android-studio, android-darkmode

I want to use dark mode in my layout. I have tried this:


**attr.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <attr name="myColor" format="reference|color" />
</resources>
```

***themes.xml:***

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    ...
    <!-- Light -->
    <item name="myColor">#4A4A4A</item>
    ...
    <!-- Dark-->
    <item name="myColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</resources>
```

***layout.xml:***

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    style="@style/HBCardContent"
    android:textDirection="locale">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/my_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World"
         android:textColor="?attr/myColor"/>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

but I got this error:

```
Unable to start activity ... Binary XML file line #53 in com.example.xxx:layout/layout: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You need to create folder for night mode and create colors.xml inside, so you will two colors.xml files in your app:

```
values/colors.xml -> <item name="myColor">#4A4A4A</item>
values-night/colors.xml -> <item name="myColor">#FFFFFF</item>
```

When you switch your app to night mode, android automatically will take color from night folder

This [link](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/appcompat-v23-2-daynight-d10f90c83e94) should help.